pip cache stuck in nodir=false mode
I get the following:
tony@tonysubuntubox:~$ pip cache
ERROR: pip cache commands can not function since cache is disabled.
I have changed both pip.config files to set no_dir_cache to false and the environment variable using unset and I still get the error message. Any help is very gratefully received.

What version of Ubuntu are you using? What is the exact command you ran to get this error? Please edit the question and add this info.

$ pip cache
ERROR: pip cache commands can not function since cache is disabled
Ubuntu 22.04.4
Any pip cache command gives the same. For example,
$pip cache purge
